# How to print git command output to python dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, git-worktree

I'm using the below git command output:
`git worktree list` into streamlit table object. For example:

```
F:/demo/a   123abc   [dev/arielma/a]
F:/demo/b   453fbd   [dev/arielma/b]
F:/demo/c   123abc   [dev/arielma/a]
F:/demo/d   3234dv   (detached HEAD)
F:/demo/e   3cxvd1   [dev/arielma/e] prunable
```

I would like to take only the valid ones (a to c) and print them to python dataframe. For example
[image: example]

where worktree name is `F:/demo/a` and its check out branch is `[dev/arielma/a]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `git worktree list --porcelain` and parse the output:

[Docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree#_porcelain_format):

> **Porcelain Format**
>
> The porcelain format has a line per attribute. Attributes are listed with a label and value separated by a single space. Boolean attributes (like bare and detached) are listed as a label only, and are present only if the value is true. Some attributes (like locked) can be listed as a label only or with a value depending upon whether a reason is available. The first attribute of a working tree is always worktree, an empty line indicates the end of the record....

Sample parsing:

```
pd.DataFrame([
    {line.split()[0]: line.split(" ",1)[1] for line in block.splitlines()}
    for block in output.split("\n\n")])
```